# different selectize dropdown should have same dropdown option values while search

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

There are two(or more) selectize dropdown where dropdown values (option values) are created by user. The issue is that two selectize should have same dropdown values when user creates some values in either of the two selectize dropdown. The dropdown values should be same and loads in other dropdown values irrespective of where they created(added).

Ref Link:- https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Fiddle Link:- http://jsfiddle.net/1oy2d6e9/

## html

```
<section class="demo" id="demo-single-item-select">
                <div class="header">
                    Single Item Select
                </div>
                <div class="sandbox">
                    <label for="select-beast">Beast:</label>
                    <select id="select-beast" class="demo-default" placeholder="create a person by typing...">
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
                         <div class="sandbox">
                    <label for="select-beast">Beast2:</label>
                    <select id="select-beast2" class="demo-default" placeholder="create a person by typing...">
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
   <div class="description">
                    These two select box have same values when values are created in either of the two.
                    <a href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/">https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/</a>
                </div>
</section>
```

## js

```
var gArr = [];

// selectize should load all dropdown values ie in gArr initially;
     $('#select-beast2').selectize({
                        create: true,
                        sortField: 'text',
                        searchField: 'item',
                        create: function(input) {
                          gArr.push(input);  //<=======storing in global variable
                            return {
                                value: input,
                                text: input
                        }
    }
                    });
                    
                     $('#select-beast').selectize({
                        create: true,
                        sortField: 'text',
                        searchField: 'item',
                        create: function(input) {
                          gArr.push(input);  //<=======storing in global variable
                            return {
                                value: input,
                                text: input
                        }
    }
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `create` function you can get the other select-box which you need to add option and then use `addOption` to add new option to that select-box .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#select-beast2').selectize({
  create: true,
  sortField: 'text',
  searchField: 'item',
  create: function(input) {
    var selectize = $('#select-beast')[0].selectize; //get another slect box
    selectize.addOption({
      value: input,
      text: input
    }); //add option to it
   
    return {
      value: input,
      text: input
    }
  }
});

$('#select-beast').selectize({
  create: true,
  sortField: 'text',
  searchField: 'item',
  create: function(input) {
    var selectize = $('#select-beast2')[0].selectize; //get another slec box
    selectize.addOption({
      value: input,
      text: input
    }); //add option to it
   
    return {
      value: input,
      text: input
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/css/selectize.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.11.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<section class="demo" id="demo-single-item-select">
  <div class="header">
    Single Item Select
  </div>
  <div class="sandbox">
    <label for="select-beast">Beast:</label>
    <select id="select-beast" class="demo-default" placeholder="create a person by typing...">
    </select>

  </div>
  <div class="sandbox">
    <label for="select-beast">Beast2:</label>
    <select id="select-beast2" class="demo-default" placeholder="create a person by typing...">
    </select>

  </div>
  <div class="description">
    These two select box have same values when values are created in either of the two.

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, the selectize inputs are auto populating other selectize inputs. The other selectize user search input should not get populated, only the dropdown values should be updated in all.

Comment: remove `selectize.addItem(input);` line that should work .Updated code as well have a look.

Comment: Swati, if have 100 multiple selectize then  var selectize = $('#select-beast2')[0].selectize; how this should be changed. Can there be generic solution.

Comment: Yes , you can loop through all selects using each loop and use `$(this)` instead of `id` .Here is [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/n93p60ha/2/) code.